# Very short (and right?) introduction into model theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

1. I have read a short introduction of model theory on a set theoretic book and noted the following lines. I wonder if my notion has some flaws or downright errors, so please look if you find it accurate or point out suspicious points. Please bear in mind that this is supposed to be just a rough sketch of what a model is and how things work.

A model is a world M in which certain axioms (logical or non-logical) are true, in short M $\vDash$ axioms.

Specifically, two things hold in M (due to logical axioms):

1. M $\nvDash$ a and ~a. (Consistency, a is just any wff).
2. If M $\vDash$ axioms and A $\vdash$ a then M $\vDash$ a.(Soundness)

An example: Let there be the axioms AX:

1. There are only 3 objects A, B, C.
2. An object can only be a banana, strawberry or orange.
3. There is at least a strawberry.

AX has for instance the following models:

M1: A, B = banana (more precise would be banana $\in$ A,B), C = strawberry.

M2: A = banana, B = strawberry, C = orange.

Now I prove some kind of CH version in AX to be unprovable in AX. CH = „The only objects are a banana or a strawberry.“

First we assume consistency of Ax and we further assume AX $\vdash$ CH. By assumption and soundness (see above) it follows M2 $\vDash$ CH. But at the same time M2 $\vDash$ ~CH. Contradiction, therefore AX $\nvdash$ CH. Now we assume AX $\vdash$ ~CH. By assumption and sound ess it follows M1 $\vDash$ ~CH. But also M1 $\vDash$ CH. Contradiction, therefore AX $\nvdash$ ~CH.

2. Then there is a short yes/no question to my upper example: Can I write for instance M1 $\vDash$ banana? Can I write M1 $\vDash$ banana = A? The first I‘d think no because banana is no wff, but the second yes, but I am unsure because $\vDash$ is the sign for logical consequence and „banana = A“ seems true just by postulation, not by consequence. Also can I write M1 $\nvDash$ banana = C as saying that the sentence is false in M1 or M1 $\vDash$ not banana = C or is both correct?

Comment: The use of $=$ in "A = banana" might not be the best choice. If $A$ = banana and $B$ = banana, does that mean $A=B$? The aside about "banana $\in A,B$" isn't a lot better - why is an object in the model a set? What says you can't have "banana $\in A$" and "orange $\in A$"? I'd go with predicates $\operatorname{Banana}(A)$, etc.

Comment: Model-axioms. Only non-logical axioms are considered, because logical axioms and laws (valid formulas) are true in every interpretation.

Comment: Your use of formulas, as per comment above, is not correct, but the exa.ple is fine. If M is a model of a set Ax of axioms and if T is a theorem proved from those axiom, then $M \vDash T$.

Comment: Yes I use some formulas very rough and anti-technical. Above I have written: 1. M $\nvDash$ a and ~a. (Consistency, a is just any wff). Is this true esp. the part that a is a wff? And then is M1 $\vDash$ „A = banana“ the right way to write it down despite that „A = banana“ is not a log. consequence but rather a set truth? (Again, just overlook that „A = banana“ is syntractical trash, it is just not important here)

Comment: Someone asked an almost identical question sometime in the last 48 hours. Was it you?

Comment: Yes. Can you maybe answer my 2nd question at the end?

Comment: As per comment above, we have to use predicates, like Banana(x). Thus, if you derive Banana(A) from your axioms, you have $M \vDash \text {Banana}(a)$.

Comment: Ok, but what about Strawberry(a) in M1 (which is false)? Do you write M1 $\nvDash$ Strawberry(a) or M1 $\vDash$ ~Strawberry(a) or doesn‘t it matter?